# R parallel S4 class cluster error

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-s4

I'm having a problem getting some code to work with the parallel package in R.  I'm using R 2.15.

Here's a simplified example... I have a file 'animal.R' which contains the following:

```
# animal.R
setClass("Animal", representation(species = "character", legs = "numeric"))

##Define some Animal methods
setGeneric("count",function(x) standardGeneric("count"))
setMethod("count", "Animal", function(x) { x@legs})

setGeneric("countAfterChopping",function(x) standardGeneric("countAfterChopping"))
setMethod("countAfterChopping", "Animal", function(x) { x@legs <- x@legs-1; x@legs})
```

Then, in my R terminal, I run:

```
library(parallel)
source('animal.R')
```

Start a local cluster of two nodes:

```
cl <- makeCluster(rep('localhost', 2))
```

Tell the cluster nodes about the Animal class:

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, parse('animal.R'))
```

Then run some code on the cluster:

```
# This works
parSapply(cl, list(daisy, fred), count)

# This doesn't...
parSapply(cl, list(daisy, fred), countAfterChopping)
```

Stop the cluster:

```
stopCluster(cl)
```

The first call to parSapply works as expected, but the second produces this error:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  2 nodes produced errors; first error: "Animal" is not a defined class
```

Any ideas what's going on?  Why doesn't the second call to parSapply work?

Comment: When you `parse` animal.R, you get an unevaluated expression, so you could either use `clusterEvalQ(cl, eval(parse('animal.R')))` or just source the script. Did that do the trick?

Comment: Ah, yes... that seems to do the trick.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here's what's going on:

For S4 objects of class "Animal", the `count` function simply extracts the `legs` slot. If this were all that you were doing, you wouldn't need to evaluate or source the file `animal.R` on your cluster nodes. All necessary information would be passed by `parSapply`.

However, the `countAfterChopping` function assigns a new value to the `legs` slot, and this is where the fun begins. The slot assignment function `` `@<-` `` contains a call to `` `slot<-` `` with the argument `check = TRUE`. This triggers an evaluation of the function `checkSlotAssignment`, which checks "that the value provided is allowed for this slot, by consulting the definition of the class" (from `?checkSlotAssignment`).

Therefore, the class definition must be known when assigning to a slot in this way, and the S4 class "Animal" is not known on the cluster nodes. This is why evaluating the parsed file `animal.R` or sourcing it works. However, you would be fine with just evaluating the first line of the file, i.e., defining the class "Animal", on each node.

Here's a reduced, reproducible example:

```
animal.R<-"
  setClass('Animal', representation(species = 'character', legs = 'numeric'))

  ##Define some Animal methods
  setGeneric('count',function(x) standardGeneric('count'))
  setMethod('count', signature(x='Animal'), function(x) { x@legs})

  setGeneric('countAfterChopping',function(x) standardGeneric('countAfterChopping'))
  setMethod('countAfterChopping', signature(x='Animal'),
    function(x) { x@legs <- x@legs-1; x@legs})
"
library(parallel)

source(textConnection(animal.R))

cl <- makeCluster(rep('localhost', 2))

daisy<-new("Animal",legs=2,species="H.sapiens")
fred<-new("Animal",legs=4,species="C.lupus")

parSapply(cl, list(daisy, fred), count)
# [1] 2 4

clusterExport(cl,"animal.R") # 
clusterEvalQ(cl,eval(parse(textConnection(animal.R),n=1)))

parSapply(cl, list(daisy, fred), countAfterChopping)
# [1] 1 3
```